# ¿Cómo evitar la selección de valores NA en FactoInvestigate?

Tags: r

Tengo un problema cuando intento ejecutar la función Investigate del paquete Factoinvestigate. En uno de mis set de datos, cuando lo intento, la función vuelve a tomar como una nueva categoria de variables los valores NA y no logro encontrar el por qué ni como solucionarlo, aquí esta un ejemplo:

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
library(missMDA)
library(FactoInvestigate)

datos1_2 = read.delim("TrueDim1_2ALL.txt")
complete1_2 = imputeMCA(datos1_2[,3:21], ncp = 5)
mca1_2 = MCA(datos1_2, tab.disj = complete1_2$tab.disj, 
             ncp = 5, quanti.sup = 1:2, na.method = "Average", graph = TRUE)
Investigate(mca1_2, file = "MCA 1_2.Rmd", document = "html_document")
```

Esto no me pasa con los demás set de datos (que son basicamente la misma tabla con algunas variables extra). Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Este es un extracto de la los datos, este mismo esta en un set de datos que funciona y uno que no funciona, ademas son estas mismas variables cuyos "NA" se toman como categoría en uno de los sets, es una tabla bastante grande y la unica diferencia entre ambas es que la que falla tiene menos variables (al extraer variables se genera el subset). Como dato extra, al hacer el MCA imputando datos, para ambas tablas el programa no toma los NA, solo pasa con Investigate.

```
compperinasal   compperiocular      compperioral    cpabeauricular

compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_1    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_1    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_1    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_1    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
NA      NA          NA      NA
NA      NA          NA      NA
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_0 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_0
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_1    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_0  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_1    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
compperinasal_1 compperiocular_0    compperioral_1  cpabeauricular_1
```

Comment: Para ayudarte es necesario un ejemplo de los datos y el código que funciona y el que no. De lo contrario no se puede reproducir el error, que parece ser específico de un subconjunto de los datos. De todas maneras mirando el código te preguntaría ¿hay `NA` en las columnas 1 y 2, las no imputadas que entran como `quanti.sup` a tu modelo? Quizás los arrastre desde ahí. Tb podrías modelar directamente sobre los datos imputados (completeObs), previa verificación de que no hay ´NA´ y que no quedó `NA` como nivel de factor. Se perdería precisión vs. la tabla disyuntiva, eso sí.

Comment: Añadi el extracto de la tabla a la pregunta. No se si sera necesario agregar las demás variables, que como mencione son muchas, pero es extraño que las mismas variables en set muy similares de datos, no funcionen en uno de los set. Cuando mencionas lo de modelar directamente te refieres a aplicar Investigate a completeObs? Si es así no se puede utilizando esa función porque toma como argumento el resultado de MCA o similares.